# How to create new Azure Subscription using Python?

Tags: python, azure-sdk-python, azure-subscription

I'm trying to programmatically create new Azure Subscriptions using the Python SDK. The only reference to the Azure Python SDK I found was [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/41e37c8a10876db40697a63e828ed7cafc19c7d6/azure-mgmt-subscription/tests/test_mgmt_subscription.py).

**Here is where I ended up with:**

```py
import azure.mgmt.billing
import azure.mgmt.subscription

creds = AzureCliCredential()
client_name = 'test'


def create_subscription(creds, client_name):
    subscription_client = azure.mgmt.subscription.SubscriptionClient(creds)
    creation_parameters = azure.mgmt.subscription.models.SubscriptionCreationParameters(
        offer_type = 'MS-AZR-0003P')
    creation_result = subscription_client.subscription_factory.create_subscription_in_enrollment_account(
        client_name,
        creation_parameters)
    
    return creation_result

output = create_subscription(creds, client_sub)

print(output)
```

**Error:** `AttributeError: module 'azure.mgmt.subscription.models' has no attribute 'SubscriptionCreationParameters'`

But looking at the [docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-subscription/0.5.0/azure.mgmt.subscription.models.html#azure.mgmt.subscription.models.SubscriptionCreationParameters) show the class `azure.mgmt.subscription.models`
has a `SubscriptionCreationParameters` module.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're using an old version of the package, subscription creation is not supported anymore. I would suggest you ask a question on https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues to ask more directly for alternative

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/21902

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the correct method to use for creating Azure subscriptions programmatically using Python would be to use the subscription client.alias.begin_create

```
creation = sub_client.alias.begin_create(alias_name="test-sub-alias",
                          body=PutAliasRequest(
                              properties=PutAliasRequestProperties(
                                  display_name="azure-sub-display",
                                  workload="Production",
                                 billing_scope="/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/BillingAccount/enrollmentAccounts/ID")))
```

The docs for this package seem like they follow that the request would issue an HTTP PUT as shown on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription-enterprise-agreement?tabs=rest